# Como devo fazer a comunicação com o DB? Recomendações de tecnologias

Tags: android, json, web-service

Estou com um projeto em Android, no qual estou tentando fazer tudo utilizando plataforma livre.

Eu preciso que os aparelhos em campo se comuniquem com o banco de dados, e escutei algo sobre JSON e Web Service.

Então eu gostaria que vocês me recomendassem, "MOSTRASSEM O CAMINHO", quais ferramentas devo utilizar para meu projeto, que ai então irei estudar elas.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O desenvolvimento para plataformas mobile, normalmente, se baseia em ferramentas já disponíveis em outras plataformas (normalmente, web). Assim, soluções mobile nada mais são que novas interfaces para a mesma aplicação, e por conta disso há diversas armadilhas que você pode enfrentar, sendo a maior de todas a repetição desnecessária de código.

#### O problema

Preciso disponibilizar minha aplicação em mais de uma plataforma, e tenho que redesenvolver código de acesso a banco de dados e regras de negócio, o que fere o preceito DRY (Don't Repeat Yourself).

#### A solução

Através do uso de webservices, você pode desenvolver apenas uma vez a lógica negocial de sua aplicação, fazendo assim com que todas as plataformas posteriores apenas consumam os métodos do webservice, reduzindo sua aplicação localizada ao desenvolvimento da interface e ao uso de `APIs` específicas (como acesso à câmera do aparelho, por exemplo).

Utilizando webservices, você terá métodos que permitam a utilização das funcionalidades da aplicação a partir de qualquer plataforma.

#### Padrões de webservice

Hoje temos dois padrões principais para webservices: `SOAP` e `REST`.

- A arquitetura `SOAP` baseia-se na definição do serviço a partir de arquivos `XML` que fornecem uma descrição dos métodos disponíveis no serviço. Chamam-se os métodos pelos seus nomes (por exemplo, `LoginUsuario`);
- A arquitetura `REST` baseia-se na utilização de verbos HTTP para descrever as operações desejadas, a saber:

  `GET`: recupera recursos
  `POST`: cria novos recursos
  `PUT`: atualiza totalmente recursos
  `PATCH`: atualiza parcialmente recursos
  `DELETE`: exclui recursos

  A utilização de recursos em webservices `REST` baseia-se especificamente no método HTTP usado para invocar o recurso, juntamente com os parâmetros. Seguindo o exemplo acima, `LoginUsuario` poderia ser uma requisição `GET` sob a arquitetura REST

#### Como implementar

Isso depende totalmente da arquitetura em que você está trabalhando. Em `.net`, uma classe de webservice `REST` tem a seguinte sintaxe:

```
public class UsuarioController : ApiController
{
    // Pode ser invocado com uma requisição GET com dois parâmetros
public string Get(string user, string key)
{
    // Operações
}
}
```

Como você está trabalhando com Android, vou supor que você trabalhe com `Java`. Como não tenho familiaridade com tal linguagem, seguem alguns links que podem te ajudar:

[Webservice SOAP em Java](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19340-01/820-6767/aeqgd/index.html)
[Webservice REST em Java](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/REST/article.html)

Comment: OK, amigo irei estudar, vou usar MYSQL+REST EM JAVA obrigado